# .NET6 Executable name defaulting to apphost.exe

Tags: c#, .net-core, csproj

We have a .NET6 project console application (in Visual Studio 2022), that has been migrated from .NET Framework 4.7.1. The project builds without issue, and produces an executable in the intermediate directory (/obj) called `apphost.exe`. However, I thought it should be possible to specify the name of the executable to be something like `<project name>.exe`. This currently happens correctly in the .NET Framework version. We have tried setting various properties in the .csproj such as `AssemblyName`, but without success. This leads to two questions:

1. Where is the "apphost" name being picked up from?
2. Can we (and if so, how do we) specify the correct exe name?

Comment: Why are you looking into `obj` instead of `bin`? obj didn't contain the actual executable in .NET Framework either. Check `bin` instead. To get the final executable use `dotnet publish`. You'll find the executable in the `bin/..../publish` folder

Comment: Seeing apphost.exe back in the obj directory is correct.  Copied from the .NET runtime, it gets patched as needed to produce either a console or run as a native Windows process (Winforms, WPF, etc) and renamed to project.exe when it gets copied to the bin directory.  This is the host executable that does the job that mscoree.dll used to do in the legacy framework and dotnet.exe in the current framework.  It determines the correct runtime version, initializes the CLR and jits the Main() method so your program can start running.  You don't have a problem, don't make it one.

Comment: If you use `dotnet publish -c Release -r win-x64 --self-contained` you'll get a self-contained, single-file executable in `bin/Release/net6.0/win-x64/publish`